# Нарисовать галочку средствами CSS

Tags: html, css, анимация, svg, checkbox

Можете подсказать, как нарисовать в CSS такую галочку(нужно именно нарисовать, а не вставить картинкой)?

[image: галочка]

Comment: Вам в чекбокс или повсеместно? А в css тоже нельзя применять `url()` ?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению нельзя. Мне просто галочку, без чекбокса). Как я понял, решения пока нет. Я применяю 2 наклонных линии, но пока безрезультатно.

Comment: смотря в чем это будет использоваться. Если нужна поддержка векторных иконок, тогда лучше использовать svg или иконочные шрифты. Можно конечно нарисовать с transform rotate, но при неоднократном использовании такой методики это будет лишь перегружать код

Comment: @Александр Агапов Добавлен свежий вариант с использованием входящим в тренд гугловских символьных шрифтов в стиле `material design`  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773972/28748

Answer (score 18):

Вариант 1

```css
[id^=c]{
    display: none;
}
[id^=c] + label{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;    
}
[id^=c] + label:before{
    content: '\2713';
    display: inline-block;
    color: green;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
[id^=c]:checked + label:before{    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" />
<label for="c1"></label>
```

Вариант 2

```css
[id^=c]{
    display: none;
}
[id^=c] + label{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
[id^=c]:checked + label span{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;    
    margin-left: -9px;   
}
[id^=c]:checked + label span:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; left: -5px;   
    width: 10px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #c00;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg);
    transform: rotate(50deg);    
}
[id^=c]:checked + label span:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; left: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #c00;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);       
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" />
<label for="c1"><span></span></label>
```

Вариант 3 (clip-path)

```css
[id^=c]{
    display: none;
}
[id^=c] + label{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;   
    position: relative;
}
[id^=c] + label:before{
    content: '';    
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(45% 64%, 84% 14%, 100% 28%, 47% 100%, 0 49%, 15% 32%);
clip-path: polygon(45% 64%, 84% 14%, 100% 28%, 47% 100%, 0 49%, 15% 32%);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
}
[id^=c]:checked + label:before{    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" />
<label for="c1"></label>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое). Но мне просто галочку желательно сделать, как если бы мы вставляли картику через url)

Answer (score 12):

Если просто галочку без чекбокса, то вот идея:

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.check-sign {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}

#check-part-1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;    
    transform:rotate(45deg); 
}

#check-part-2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;    
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: 16px;
    top: -19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="check-part-1" class="check-sign"></div>
    <div id="check-part-2" class="check-sign"></div>
</div>
```

Идея в том, чтобы нарисовать два прямоугольника и расположить их под прямыми углами относительно друг друга. Естественно это надо делать в их общем контейнере.
С размерами и расположением если захотите, можете сами потом поиграться и сделать как вам нужно

Answer (score 9):

**Анимация галочки начинается после клика мышкой**

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="94" height="94" viewBox="0 0 47 47"  >
 <title>animation icon -OK-</title> 
       <circle fill="#4CAF50" cx="24" cy="24" r="21"/>
         <path class="path" fill= "none" stroke ="#CCFF90" stroke-width ="1.5" stroke-dasharray= "70.2" stroke-dashoffset="70.2" 
   d="M 34.6 14.6  L 21 28.2 L 15.4 22.6 L 12.6 25.4 L 21 33.8 L 37.4 17.4z">
   <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" values="70.2;0" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
   <animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin = "p1.end" values="#4CAF50; #CCFF90"  dur="1s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: SMIL сейчас deprecated, в Chrome когда-нибудь выпилят, а в IE/Edge никогда и не работало.

Comment: @Qwertiy уже, как два года deprecated и до сих пор жив и как говорится нет ничего более постоянного, чем временное Посмотри caniuse еще на 5 будущих версий вперед продлили

Comment: Но в IE/Edge всё равно нет и не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy IE/Edge да, согласен, но кроме smil эти браузеры и многое другое делают очень криво. Но факт, остается фактом, SVG набирает популярность, особенно за бугром, недаром начиная c ie11 поддержка SVG выросла

Answer (score 7):

Постарался повторить и упростить

```css
i.check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -3px 10px 3px;
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 15px 15px 0;
  transform: rotate( 45deg);
}
```

```html
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<!-- галочка css -->
<i class='check'></i>


<br />

<!-- картинка для сравнения -->
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4kS2.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 7):

Просто check галочка, просто SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="red"><path d="M20.285 2l-11.285 11.567-5.286-5.011-3.714 3.716 9 8.728 15-15.285z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Простейшая галочка. Толщину и цвет регулируйте сами:

```css
.select_header {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.select_header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 7px solid #f88e11;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #f88e11;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="select_header">Выберите язык</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Такое простое решение:

```css
.checkmark {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 14px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.checkmark_stem {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #e84245;
  left: 25px;
  top: -8px;
}
.checkmark_kick {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #e84245;
  left: 12px;
  top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkmark">
<div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
<div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Самая простая в мире галочка :

```css
i {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<i> &#10004;</i>
```

Источник : https://html5book.ru/specsimvoly-html/

Comment: Вы же просто символ написали, а надо нарисовать.

Answer (score 4):

*Ещё один вариант*

Хорошо подойдёт для приложений, которые выполняются в стиле *Material design*, шрифт адаптирован для мобильных версий.

Галочку можно легко внедрить в HTML с помощью [символьного шрифта от Google](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html), достаточно просто подключить символьный шрифт и написать название иконки.

Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)

*Подключение шрифта:*

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">`

**Ниже пример использования.**

Работает во всех браузерах. `IE` поддерживает начиная с 10 версии.

```css
   i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.green{color:yellowgreen;}
.red{color: red; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons green">done</i>
<i class="material-icons red">error</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://fontawesome.io/icon/check/

```css
i {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Очень приближенно, для раскрытия метода:

```css
#triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 26px solid transparent;
  border-right: 26px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
}
#triangle-down:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   left:0;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 26px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid transparent;
   border-top: 50px solid #fff;
}
#triangle-down:after {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-down">

</div>
```

Основная ссылка на примеры : [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Кое-что на Хабре : [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/161041/)

Comment: Спасибо). Но пока получается треугольник перевернутый). Скорее всего здесь надо действовать линиями)