# Поддержка лигатурных иконок браузерами

Tags: css, веб-программирование, svg, шрифты, кроссбраузерность

[Наткнулся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770072/178988) на интересную штуку - шрифт, в котором вместо иконки ты пишешь слово, а оно показывается как иконка. Не знаю, как сделано именно тут, но единственный известный мне способ сделать такое - это лигатуры в шрифте.

Меня интересует кроссбраузерность этого подхода.

```css
.material-icons.material-icons {
  font-size: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons">home</i>
```

Comment: На сайте иконок есть [такая табличка](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html) поддерживаемых браузеров, на [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature) примерно такая же табличка получается

Comment: @diraria, по идее, должно ещё от ОС зависеть, или ошибаюсь?

Comment: может и должно, но я не знаю, так как слово лигатура сегодня узнал)

Comment: Ух ты крутота какая) Хотя мне немножко не нравится, что при загрузке может успеть моргнуть слово home обычным шрифтом

Comment: @andreymal, если ты используешь нормальный css, то не может - текст с незагруженными шрифтами не отображается. Ну кроме случаев, когда ты намеренно или ненамеренно (webpack, блин) подгружешь стили динамически.

Comment: Ну фиг знает, я жму плей в стаковерфлововском сниппете и там слово home на мгновение моргает)

Comment: Что-то доволи похоже на иконки google material design и того же bootstrap. Если принцип один и тот же, то мигания никакого не будет, я как-то проводил с ними эксперименты во всех популярных браузерах.

Comment: @VladSpirin, нет, принцип другой. Там символ, которого нет, а тут слово. А ещё слово сможет прочитать скрин-ридер.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Кратковременное мигание действительно есть во всех браузерах. Сначала слово `Home`, затем иконка подгружается. При повторном включении мигания нет, иконка уже в кеше находится. Некоторые видят мигание, другие нет, всё зависит наверное от скорости инета у конкретного пользователя.

Comment: @Alexandr_T у меня даже при повторном включении мигание есть. Редко, через раз, но есть

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Короткий ответ:*

1. Сделано это с помощью подключения [символьного шрифта от Google](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#what-are-material-icons-)

   Краткая аннотация от Google:
   Шрифт обеспечивает читаемость и четкость символов, как больших, так и малых размеров. Эти иконки оптимизированы для красивого отображения на всех распространенных платформах и разрешениях дисплея.
2. Поддерживается всеми современными браузерами. Поддержка `IE`,
   начинается с `IE10`.

[Таблица поддержки символьных шрифтов браузерами.](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html)

*Более подробно:*

Всё началось в 2012 году.

Разработчики `github.com` решили повысить производительность своего сервиса и заменить множество различных иконочных шрифтов одним своим стандартным `Octicons`, который  отвечал бы всем их потребностям в отображении иконок.
Скачать шрифт можно [здесь](https://octicons.github.com)

В марте 2013 года портал **alistapart** выпускает свою аналитическую статью -
 [The Era of Symbol Fonts](http://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts)

В которой автор рассказывает о преимуществах и некоторых недостатка применения символьных шрифтов.
Автор статьи пишет, что **шрифт, как векторное изображение поддерживается всеми браузерами вплоть до IE6**.

*Я перевел заключительную часть статьи, заранее извиняюсь за вольный перевод*

**Проблемы с шрифтами**

Любой хороший дизайнер скажет вам, что значок или логотип будут иметь тонкие различия дизайна для разных размеров шрифтов, таких как, изменение толщины линии или даже уменьшение некоторых деталей при небольших размерах.
 Однако с символьными шрифтами вы не можете создавать альтернативные варианты для разных размеров шрифта.

Если вам нужны разные рисунки при изменении размера шрифта то, вам необходимо дублировать иконку в файле шрифта и выбрать соответствующий глиф в зависимости от использования.

Это тоже проблематично, потому что вы не представляете, как конечный пользователь действительно просмотрит ваш дизайн.  Увеличение размера шрифта в их браузере изначально не приведет к изменению дизайна символа.

Для большинства из нас это не проблема, так как многие иконки, которые мы используем сегодня для фидов и социальных сетей, относительно хорошо знакомы нам.

Другая важная проблема с использованием символьного шрифта заключается в том, что вы получаете только один цвет. Вы можете использовать магию с цветами фона и градиентами шрифта для эмуляции двухцветного логотипа, но если ваши иконки многоцветны, то текущая настройка шрифта символов не будет работать для вас.

Чтобы исправить это, Apple предлагает многоцветные шрифты, которые позволят вам создавать и вставлять чистую векторную графику на любую веб-страницу.

Первой попыткой в этой области является шрифт [Apple Color Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Color_Emoji), который вы, возможно, уже имеете, если на вашем компьютере работает `OSX Lion`

---

**Google Material Icons**

Google воплотил  идеи символьного шрифта в реальность и создал свой [символьный шрифт](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html) svg иконок, который включает в себя 900 изображений.

Подключение шрифта:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Выбирать иконки по названиям можно [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)  (*см. Update*)

Пример использования гугловского символьного шрифта:

*Наведите курсор на иконки*

```css
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.red{color:red}
.green{color:yellowgreen}
.blue{color: dodgerblue}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons red">settings</i> 
<i class="material-icons green">android</i>
<i class="material-icons blue">stars</i>
```

Проверена работоспособность FF, Chrome, Opera, IE11.
К сожалению не имею возможности проверить работоспособность на более старых версиях IE и Safari

### Update 27.01.2018

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Для иконок символьного шрифта с названиями в несколько слов, например
- `note add` необходимо отдельные слова соединять нижним подчеркиванием `note_add`
- Также имеется возможность поддерживать IE более старых версий: IE9 и
  ниже.
  Для этого в [таблице шрифтов](https://material.io/icons/#ic_offline_pin) выберите нужную иконку и нажмите <kbd>ICON FONT</kbd> и заберите образец вставки:

`<!-- For IE9 or below. -->
<i class="material-icons">&#xE90A;</i>`

*Ниже комбинированный пример для современных браузеров и для старых версий `IE`*

```css
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.red{color:red;}
.green{color:yellowgreen;}
.blue{color: dodgerblue;}
.grey{color: grey;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="material-icons red">note_add</i> 

<!-- For modern browsers. -->
<i class="material-icons grey">offline_pin</i>
<!-- For IE9 or below. -->
<i class="material-icons">&#xE90A;</i>

<i class="material-icons blue">speaker_notes</i>
```

*Связанный пример:*

[Нарисовать галочку средствами CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773972/28748)

Comment: И где здесь ответ на фразы «Не знаю, как сделано именно тут» и «Меня интересует кроссбраузерность этого подхода»?

Comment: @Arhad в тексте статьи жирным шрифтом - поддерживается всеми браузерами. На вопрос как сделано - спец. шрифт гугловский подключается, -конец статьи моего ответа

Comment: @Alexandr_T лично мне из текста ответа неочевидно, что IE6 поддерживает именно лигатуры (и поддерживает ли вообще). Тот же Octicons вроде как без лигатур работает

Comment: @andreymal я не могу со 100% уверенностью подтвердить, что IE6 поддерживает лигатуры (не на чем проверить:)), но почитай оригинал статьи, которую я указал в ссылке http://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts и ещё можно попросить пользователей `windows xp` с родным `IE6` проверить работоспособность примера

Comment: @andreymal ты прав - вот же табличка поддержки шрифтов с лигатурами https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html поддержка IE начинается только с 10 версии

Comment: @andreymal  и всё таки поддерживает IE ниже 10 версии см. Update 27,01,2018  в ответе

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну это же явно не лигатуры, а обыкновенный символ из области для частного использования :)

Comment: не а, не правильно, это лигатуры с использованием  Юникода

Comment: лигатуры это множество вариантов исполнения одного и того же символа в юникодах. ну там ножка буквы более выпуклая или какие-то другие различия

Comment: @Alexandr_TT лигатура — это [по определению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2)) изображение из *нескольких* символов. В вашем апдейте для IE9 используется *один* символ E90A — это явно не лигатура

Comment: @Alexandr_TT более того, ваш апдейт ещё больше подтверждает отсутствие лигатур для IE9, раз для него пришлось писать отдельный пример с отдельным символом, который ну совсем никак не похож на английское слово :)

Comment: @ Это не мой апдейт, это сразу было в гугловских шрифтах, я просто не заметил сразу, когда писал в первый раз и сегодня просто добавил