# Почему не отображаются svg-иконки на icomoon?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Они загружаются, но видны как пустые блоки. Пробовал другие иконки - все нормально. А вот именно из этого проекта ни одна не срабатывает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для использования в веб-шрифтах svg-иконка должна иметь заливку черным цветом, причем не обводка, а само содержимое. Если иконка нарисована просто толстыми линиями, необходимо обконтурить обводку. Я использую "Inkscape SVG" для этих целей

Answer (score 3):

Есть  более современный способ включения иконок в свой проект, это - [символьный шрифт от Google](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#what-are-material-icons-)

Это 900 качественных, адаптивных иконок, которые добавляются в проект очень быстро, путём подключения шрифта и добавления имени иконки.

*Подключение шрифта:*

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">`

*Выбирать иконки по названиям можно* [здесь](https://material.io/icons/)

**Пример использования гугловского символьного шрифта:**

```css
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.red{color:red; }
.green{color:green;}
.blue{color: dodgerblue;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons blue">important_devices</i>
<i class="material-icons green">offline_pin</i>
<i class="material-icons red">contact_phone</i>
```

- Как вы заметили, можно менять цвет иконок из внешнего файла css.
- Ещё одно преимущество применения этого шрифта,- в любой момент вы
  можете в любом месте проекта заменить одну иконку на другую, изменив
  лишь её имя.

Более подробно об использовании гугловского символьного шрифта [в другом топике нашего сайта.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770153/28748)

Comment: Так суть icomoon в создании собственного иконочного шрифта, думаю вместо данного ответа, можно было дать то, что просит автор, а не перечислять штуки вроде  MDI или fontawesome :)  (P.S. Да, вопрос был задан давно, просто захотелось ответить)

Comment: @FrogFrogov Сделайте свой ответ, с примерами в дополнение к комментарию

Answer (score 0):

**Дополняю принятый ответ (на случай, если вдруг кому пригодиться)**:

1. Попробуйте обесцветить иконки в самом интерфейсе .icomoon
2. Вы залили многоцветные иконки, icomoon плохо относиться к многоцветным иконкам.
3. У .svg исходников битый код
4. Позиционирование картинки за видимую область 
   (попробуйте сделать *move* в веб интерфейсе .icomoon)