# Использование <use> в SVG на устройствах Apple

Tags: html, ios, svg

На странице имеется общая SVG с символами. Далее символы используются как `<svg><use href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg>`. Проблема в следующем - на любых устройствах не от Apple - стрелочка отображается как надо, а вот на устройствах от Apple - нет. Вне зависимости от браузера. На Apple в `<use>` нету ничего, а на других устройствах - там как и положено `shadow-root`. В чем может быть причина - не могу понять.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute">
    <symbol id="icon-arrow" viewBox="0 0 10.344 16.18">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M2.72 1.29l6.61 6.8-6.61 6.8"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-bullets-menu1" viewBox="0 0 28 48">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M20 12.156V8h1a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V1a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H7a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v6a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h1v4.143c-2.086.908-8 3.843-8 7.94V42.6A5.582 5.582 0 0 0 5.606 48h16.787A5.583 5.583 0 0 0 28 42.6V20.082c0-3.918-5.938-6.982-8-7.926zM8 2h12v4H8V2zm1.365 11.74a1 1 0 0 0 .635-.932V8h8v4.808a1 1 0 0 0 .615.923c1.917.8 7.385 3.69 7.385 6.352V22H2v-1.918c0-2.816 5.455-5.592 7.365-6.342zM26 38H2V24h24v14zm-3.607 8H5.606A3.6 3.6 0 0 1 2 42.6V40h24v2.6a3.6 3.6 0 0 1-3.607 3.4z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-bullets-menu2" viewBox="0 0 47.875 40.032">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M47.615 1.194a1.027 1.027 0 0 0-.727-.333L16.962.004a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-1.04.926c-.01.16-1.138 16.145-5.23 24.758a.983.983 0 0 0 .49 1.317 1.02 1.02 0 0 0 1.344-.48c3.71-7.8 5.035-20.857 5.343-24.51l27.885.8c-1.54 16.528-5.35 34.31-10.24 35.186a1.736 1.736 0 0 1-.192.025h-.31c-1.884-.154-4.23-2.924-6.672-7.913a1.015 1.015 0 0 0-.888-.563l-26.432-.6a1.086 1.086 0 0 0-.8.36.973.973 0 0 0-.21.84c.084.384 2.144 9.407 9.6 9.58 7.846.18 22.473.265 25.255.28.1.006.2.01.294.01a4.22 4.22 0 0 0 .724-.065c8.15-1.46 11.233-29.437 11.988-38.015a.983.983 0 0 0-.257-.746zm-37.96 36.55c-4.415-.1-6.52-4.558-7.3-6.78l24.432.553A25.24 25.24 0 0 0 31.11 38c-5.604-.034-15.496-.115-21.456-.254zm28.64-26.5h.036a.992.992 0 1 0 .036-1.985l-15.262-.527a.992.992 0 1 0-.072 1.982zm-17.36 5.213a1 1 0 0 0 .976 1.027l14.267.492h.036a.992.992 0 1 0 .035-1.984L21.982 15.5a1 1 0 0 0-1.047.96zm-1.807 6.79a1 1 0 0 0 .976 1.027l8.142.28h.036a.992.992 0 1 0 .035-1.982l-8.142-.28a1.03 1.03 0 0 0-1.047.96z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-bullets-menu3" viewBox="0 0 47.969 44.031">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M46.963 24.314H36.497l-4.3-9.658a1.015 1.015 0 0 0-1.917.222l-4.153 22.828L18.645.78a1 1 0 0 0-.978-.793 1.05 1.05 0 0 0-1 .77L10.82 26.32h-9.8a.987.987 0 1 0 0 1.974h10.608a1 1 0 0 0 .985-.772l4.982-21.767 7.6 37.483a1 1 0 0 0 .99.8h.01a1 1 0 0 0 .983-.814l4.507-24.78 3.234 7.258a1.008 1.008 0 0 0 .923.59H46.97a.99.99 0 1 0-.007-1.978z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-bullets-menu4" viewBox="0 0 48 47.969">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M47.187 24.134L23.677.788a2.99 2.99 0 0 0-2.267-.8L2.7.088a2.742 2.742 0 0 0-2.694 2.74l.092 19.088a2.784 2.784 0 0 0 .8 1.925l.194.19c23.5 23.415 23.876 23.584 24.115 23.69a2.675 2.675 0 0 0 1.128.25 2.72 2.72 0 0 0 1.92-.8L47.2 27.992a2.73 2.73 0 0 0-.013-3.86zm-1.408 2.444L26.834 45.755a.707.707 0 0 1-.5.207c-.1 0-.194-.02-.135.027-.682-.54-9.985-9.717-23.7-23.38l-.188-.19a.74.74 0 0 1-.217-.512L2.003 2.82a.72.72 0 0 1 .712-.723l17.792-.085.9-.02a1.055 1.055 0 0 1 .857.222L45.776 25.56a.712.712 0 0 1 .21.508.72.72 0 0 1-.207.51zM7.663 7.644a4.928 4.928 0 0 0 0 6.946 4.905 4.905 0 0 0 6.927-6.946 5.01 5.01 0 0 0-6.926 0zm5.51 5.526a2.96 2.96 0 0 1-4.094 0 2.91 2.91 0 0 1 0-4.105 2.9 2.9 0 0 1 4.095 4.105z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-bullets-menu5" viewBox="0 0 48 41.937">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M30.927 10.118H7.257A7.284 7.284 0 0 0 0 17.235v10.06a7.3 7.3 0 0 0 7.258 7.142H8v4.96a2.408 2.408 0 0 0 2.32 2.534 2.367 2.367 0 0 0 1.633-.68l7.07-6.813h11.9A7.116 7.116 0 0 0 38 27.294v-10.06a7.1 7.1 0 0 0-7.073-7.116zM36 27.294a5.1 5.1 0 0 1-5.073 5.116H18.622a.988.988 0 0 0-.69.28l-7.345 7.08c-.166.16-.585.147-.587-.372v-5.975a1.006 1.006 0 0 0-1-1.013H7.258A5.258 5.258 0 0 1 2 27.294v-10.06a5.246 5.246 0 0 1 5.258-5.09h23.67A5.087 5.087 0 0 1 36 17.234v10.06zm4.554-27.31h-19.7a6.91 6.91 0 0 0-6.8 6.558 1.01 1.01 0 0 0 .9 1.1 1 1 0 0 0 1.09-.915 4.877 4.877 0 0 1 4.814-4.72h19.7A5.476 5.476 0 0 1 46 7.23v7.85a5.32 5.32 0 0 1-4.713 5.182 1.014 1.014 0 0 0 .11 2.02 1.088 1.088 0 0 0 .115-.005A7.364 7.364 0 0 0 48 15.08V7.23a7.446 7.446 0 0 0-7.446-7.25zm-11.692 24.32H9.034a1.013 1.013 0 0 0 0 2.026h19.828a1.013 1.013 0 0 0 0-2.026zm0-6.08H9.034a1.014 1.014 0 0 0 0 2.027h19.828a1.014 1.014 0 0 0 0-2.026z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-bullets-menu6" viewBox="0 0 36 48">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M30.27 3.98H25V1a1 1 0 1 0-2 0v2.98h-4V1a1 1 0 1 0-2 0v2.98h-4V1a1 1 0 1 0-2 0v2.98H5.73A5.738 5.738 0 0 0 0 9.713v32.554A5.737 5.737 0 0 0 5.73 48h24.54A5.737 5.737 0 0 0 36 42.268V9.714a5.738 5.738 0 0 0-5.73-5.733zM34 42.27A3.736 3.736 0 0 1 30.27 46H5.73A3.736 3.736 0 0 1 2 42.268V9.714a3.736 3.736 0 0 1 3.73-3.732H11v1.006a1 1 0 1 0 2 0V5.982h4v1.006a1 1 0 1 0 2 0V5.982h4v1.006a1 1 0 1 0 2 0V5.982h5.268A3.736 3.736 0 0 1 34 9.714v32.554zm-7.137-26.282H9.01a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h17.853a1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm0 8H9.01a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h17.853a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.996zm0 8H9.01a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h17.853a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.993z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-close" viewBox="0 0 15.642 15.642">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.882 7.82l6.54-6.54a.75.75 0 1 0-1.06-1.06l-6.54 6.54L1.28.22A.75.75 0 1 0 .22 1.28l6.54 6.542-6.54 6.54a.75.75 0 0 0 1.06 1.06l6.54-6.54 6.542 6.54a.75.75 0 1 0 1.06-1.06l-6.54-6.54z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-doc" viewBox="0 0 35 47">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M35 47H.01V10.71L10.643 0H35v47zM1.47 45.53h32.07V1.468H11.246l-9.778 9.85V45.53zm10.205-33.78H.74v-1.47h9.475V.735h1.458V11.75z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-drag-and-drop" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <path d="M88.63 12.97C76 16.03 69.5 22.53 69.5 32.29c0 16.83 10.14 23.72 29.65 20.28 6.5-1.34 18.17-2.3 25.64-2.3 12.82 0 14.35-.38 19.51-5.55 9.57-9.76 6.89-26.21-5.36-32.52-5.54-2.87-37.3-2.3-50.31.77zm115.36-.96c-2.49.96-6.12 4.59-8.23 8.04-5.36 8.61-4.02 17.98 3.83 24.87 5.74 5.36 5.93 5.36 34.05 5.36 23.72 0 28.7-.57 32.14-3.44 10.52-8.42 11.29-20.85 1.91-30.23l-6.5-6.5-26.4.19c-14.73-.01-28.5.75-30.8 1.71zM322.8 16.6c-9.37 9.37-8.61 21.81 1.91 30.23 3.44 2.87 8.42 3.44 32.14 3.44 28.12 0 28.31 0 34.05-5.36 10.91-9.57 8.04-27.93-4.97-32.91-2.68-1.15-16.45-1.91-30.8-1.91H329.3l-6.5 6.51zm128.37-4.21c-7.08 3.83-10.52 9.95-10.52 18.37 0 6.7 1.15 9.38 5.55 13.97l5.55 5.55h58.15l5.55-5.55c4.4-4.4 5.55-7.27 5.55-13.58 0-17.79-6.31-21.04-40.56-21.04-14.73-.01-26.98.94-29.27 2.28zM569.4 35.73c-6.51 3.06-12.05 11.67-12.05 18.94 0 2.49 2.11 7.46 4.78 11.1 10.33 14.16 13.78 20.09 16.07 26.78 3.06 9.37 9.76 15.3 19.13 16.45 6.89.96 8.42.38 14.54-5.74 5.36-5.36 6.7-8.23 6.7-14.16 0-17.03-24.29-52.99-37.3-55.1-3.07-.56-8.43.2-11.87 1.73zM23.39 72.27c-8.03 4.4-11.67 16.26-12.63 40.18-1.15 24.11.38 29.84 9.38 35.39 8.03 4.97 17.6 3.83 24.3-2.87 4.4-4.4 5.17-7.08 6.7-26.4 2.68-35.58 2.68-37.12-2.87-42.66-6.13-5.93-17.8-7.85-24.88-3.64zm564.37 84.94l-5.55 5.55v58.16l5.55 5.55c4.4 4.4 7.27 5.55 13.58 5.55 17.6 0 21.04-6.31 21.04-40.18 0-14.73-.96-26.78-2.1-29.27-3.63-7.27-9.76-10.91-18.55-10.91-6.69.01-9.37 1.16-13.97 5.55zM18.61 197.2c-7.27 5.74-8.42 10.71-8.42 36.73 0 33.86 3.44 40.18 21.04 40.18 6.31 0 9.18-1.15 13.58-5.55l5.55-5.55v-58.16l-5.55-5.55c-4.59-4.4-7.27-5.55-13.97-5.55-4.96.01-9.93 1.35-12.23 3.45zm570.69 82.65c-3.64 2.87-7.65 3.83-17.41 3.83-18.37 0-32.14 5.74-45.34 18.94-5.93 5.93-11.86 13.97-13.2 17.79-2.29 6.5-3.25 7.08-7.46 5.74-8.8-2.49-31.38-1.15-39.41 2.3-17.6 7.46-31.95 22.77-37.31 39.79-2.1 7.27-2.3 7.27-12.44 7.27-30.42 0-57.78 24.87-61.79 56.25l-1.34 11.28-8.8 2.49c-18.94 5.55-36.92 23.34-42.28 41.51-1.15 4.4-2.3 13.77-2.1 20.66.19 18.17 6.89 31.95 23.72 48.79l13.2 13.01v26.2l-6.5-6.7-6.31-6.89h-18.56c-17.98 0-18.75.19-24.3 5.55-6.31 6.31-7.46 15.88-2.87 24.87 3.83 7.27 10.52 9.76 27.17 9.76 16.26 0 24.11-3.06 28.31-10.91 2.49-4.78 2.68-2.49 3.44 25.25.77 25.44 1.53 32.33 4.97 40.94 5.36 13.58 15.88 29.08 26.4 39.22l8.42 8.23v86.86c0 70.79.57 89.15 2.87 99.1 8.61 36.35 39.6 67.15 75.95 75.76 18.17 4.21 436.58 4.21 454.75 0 17.79-4.21 33.86-13.58 48.02-27.74 14.16-14.16 23.53-30.23 27.74-48.02 4.21-18.17 4.21-436.58 0-454.75-8.61-36.35-39.41-67.34-75.76-75.95-10.14-2.3-30.23-2.87-115.55-2.87H692.22l-35.01-35.01c-34.06-34.05-34.82-35.01-34.82-42.85 0-4.4-.96-10.33-2.29-13.01-4.6-10.14-21.62-13.96-30.8-6.69zm-4.02 49.55c12.43 8.99 75.95 74.8 85.33 88.2 25.63 36.54 37.11 80.92 32.14 123.59-10.33 85.9-74.8 150.95-159.75 161.28-22.38 2.68-102.92 2.68-116.13 0-19.13-4.02-35.97-17.41-44-35.2-3.44-7.84-4.4-13.77-4.97-33.48l-.77-23.91 26.59 26.21c25.44 25.06 27.17 26.4 34.44 26.4 13.97 0 24.3-13.58 19.7-26.02-1.15-3.06-27.93-31.38-59.5-62.94l-57.2-57.58v-8.8c0-15.11 12.05-25.06 27.55-22.96 4.4.77 12.82 7.84 33.86 28.31 26.59 26.21 28.51 27.55 35.58 27.55 13.97 0 24.3-13.77 19.7-26.02-1.15-3.06-15.3-18.94-31.38-35.2-32.52-32.91-34.82-36.54-28.51-49.36 4.59-9.57 14.54-14.73 24.49-13.01 5.93 1.15 11.29 5.17 27.74 21.24 11.29 10.91 22.57 20.47 25.25 21.04 7.08 1.72 17.98-3.44 21.43-10.33 6.12-11.86 4.21-16.64-15.31-36.73-13.58-13.97-14.16-15.11-14.16-23.72 0-7.65.96-9.95 6.5-15.5 5.74-5.74 7.65-6.5 16.26-6.5 9.76 0 10.14.19 25.64 15.11 8.61 8.42 17.98 15.69 20.66 16.45 7.27 1.72 18.17-3.44 21.62-10.33 4.4-8.23 3.83-13.77-2.49-23.34-3.06-4.59-6.12-10.71-6.89-13.39-1.72-7.27 3.45-18.17 10.91-22.77 8.83-5.37 16.87-4.8 25.67 1.71zm317 91.06c19.7 5.17 31.95 15.69 41.32 35.39l4.97 10.52v434.28l-4.97 10.52c-7.08 15.3-15.5 23.91-30.04 30.99l-12.82 6.31H466.47l-10.52-4.97c-19.7-9.38-30.23-21.62-35.39-41.32-2.3-8.8-2.87-25.63-2.87-84.75v-73.66l56.82.57c36.35.38 63.71-.19 75.18-1.53 98.33-12.25 177.54-89.34 192.27-186.91 6.31-41.9 1.34-82.07-15.31-121.29-3.63-8.8-6.7-16.26-6.7-16.45 0-.38 38.65-.57 85.71-.57 69.65 0 87.63.58 96.62 2.87zM20.14 320.02c-3.44 2.1-7.08 6.12-8.04 8.8-1.15 2.68-1.91 16.45-1.91 30.8v25.83l6.5 6.5c9.37 9.37 21.81 8.61 30.23-1.91 2.87-3.44 3.44-8.42 3.44-32.14 0-28.12 0-28.31-5.17-34.05-7.07-7.85-16.44-9.18-25.05-3.83zM16.5 447.25l-6.5 6.5.57 28.89c.58 28.31.58 28.69 5.93 33.86 4.21 4.21 7.08 5.36 13.97 5.36 7.46 0 9.57-.96 14.35-6.31l5.55-6.12v-26.78c0-29.08-1.53-35.01-9.76-39.41-9.18-4.6-16.64-3.46-24.11 4.01zm30.81 111.91c-6.89 2.68-12.24 11.29-12.24 19.71 0 6.89 1.15 8.99 9.76 17.22 12.05 11.67 33.86 22.38 45.34 22.38 15.5 0 24.11-14.73 17.22-29.65-1.34-3.25-6.89-6.89-16.64-11.67-8.04-3.83-16.64-8.8-19.32-11.29-9.2-8.23-15.71-10.14-24.12-6.7zm112.87 26.4c-10.52 8.42-11.29 20.85-1.72 30.42l6.5 6.5 28.89-.57c28.31-.57 28.7-.57 33.86-5.93 4.21-4.21 5.36-7.08 5.36-13.97 0-7.46-.96-9.57-6.31-14.35l-6.12-5.55h-28.31c-23.73.01-28.71.58-32.15 3.45z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-first-link-lines" viewBox="0 0 16 12">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1 0a1 1 0 1 1-1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm4 0h10a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zM1 5a1 1 0 1 1-1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm4 0h10a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm-4 5a1 1 0 1 1-1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm4 0h10a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 1 1 0-2z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-instagram" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M12 2.163c3.204 0 3.584.012 4.85.07 3.252.148 4.77 1.69 4.92 4.92.057 1.264.068 1.644.068 4.848 0 3.206-.012 3.585-.07 4.85-.148 3.225-1.663 4.77-4.918 4.92-1.266.057-1.644.07-4.85.07-3.204 0-3.584-.013-4.85-.07-3.26-.15-4.77-1.7-4.918-4.92-.058-1.266-.07-1.645-.07-4.85 0-3.204.013-3.583.07-4.85.15-3.226 1.664-4.77 4.92-4.918 1.265-.057 1.644-.07 4.848-.07zM12 0C8.74 0 8.333.014 7.053.072 2.695.272.273 2.69.073 7.052.013 8.332 0 8.742 0 12c0 3.26.014 3.668.072 4.948.2 4.358 2.618 6.78 6.98 6.98 1.28.058 1.69.072 4.948.072 3.26 0 3.668-.014 4.948-.072 4.354-.2 6.782-2.618 6.98-6.98.058-1.28.072-1.69.072-4.948 0-3.26-.014-3.667-.072-4.947-.196-4.354-2.617-6.78-6.98-6.98C15.67.013 15.26 0 12 0zm0 5.838a6.162 6.162 0 1 0 0 12.324 6.162 6.162 0 0 0 0-12.324zM12 16a4 4 0 1 1 0-8 4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm6.406-11.845a1.44 1.44 0 1 0 0 2.88 1.44 1.44 0 0 0 0-2.88z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-phone" viewBox="0 0 12 16">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M11 0H1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V1a1 1 0 0 0-1-1zm-1 14H2V2h8v12zM5 5h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2zm1 6a1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0-1-1z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-phone2" viewBox="0 0 45.813 45.906">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M30.644 27.712a1.97 1.97 0 0 0-2.71-.035s-2.678 2.61-2.93 2.745c-1.573 0-5.566-3.324-8.06-6.712-1.492-2.03-1.655-3.03-1.656-3.142l2.89-2.817a1.92 1.92 0 0 0 .024-2.72L8.758 5.44a1.936 1.936 0 0 0-2.734-.026c-.312.3-.636.61-.965.918-2.338 2.2-4.987 4.688-5.067 8.8-.1 4.917 3.534 10.938 11.42 18.947 7.943 8.067 13.943 11.824 18.883 11.824 4.327 0 7.005-2.893 9.368-5.445l.5-.54a1.92 1.92 0 0 0-.037-2.664zm7.57 11.41c-2.29 2.474-4.453 4.813-7.916 4.81-4.316 0-10.033-3.672-17.476-11.232-7.388-7.5-10.94-13.24-10.855-17.536.064-3.282 2.292-5.378 4.447-7.4a11.15 11.15 0 0 0 .933-.946l9.448 9.533-2.912 2.843c-.652.684-.686 1.716-.1 3.07 1.53 3.542 7.895 10.13 11.223 10.127a2.283 2.283 0 0 0 1.027-.227 2.58 2.58 0 0 0 .386-.268c.175-.163 2.81-2.727 2.822-2.8l9.476 9.48zm-1.052-17.766a.984.984 0 0 0 .953 1.014h.034a.984.984 0 0 0 .984-.95A14.29 14.29 0 0 0 24.316 6.664a.985.985 0 0 0-.953 1.015 1.007 1.007 0 0 0 1.02.95 12.318 12.318 0 0 1 12.78 12.726zm2.516-15.23a20.73 20.73 0 0 0-15.35-6.12.985.985 0 0 0-.966 1 1.04 1.04 0 0 0 1.008.96 18.99 18.99 0 0 1 19.48 19.4.983.983 0 0 0 .966 1h.02a.984.984 0 0 0 .988-.96 20.733 20.733 0 0 0-6.146-15.28zm-16.316 8.247a.963.963 0 0 0 1.05.916 5.77 5.77 0 0 1 4.408 1.643 5.664 5.664 0 0 1 1.652 4.39.983.983 0 0 0 .92 1.045h.066a.986.986 0 0 0 .984-.917 7.644 7.644 0 0 0-8.16-8.125.985.985 0 0 0-.92 1.048z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-phone3" viewBox="0 0 58 98">
        <path class="st0" d="M48 0H10C4.5 0 0 4.5 0 10v78c0 5.5 4.5 10 10 10h38c5.5 0 10-4.5 10-10V10c0-5.5-4.5-10-10-10zM29 94c-3.9 0-7-2.2-7-5s3.1-5 7-5 7 2.2 7 5-3.1 5-7 5zm21-15H8V13h42v66z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-popup-close" viewBox="-35 36.4 28.6 28.6">
        <path class="st0" d="M-7.3 37.2c1.2 1.2 1.2 3.1 0 4.2L-29.9 64c-1.2 1.2-3.1 1.2-4.2 0-1.2-1.2-1.2-3.1 0-4.2l22.6-22.6c1.1-1.1 3-1.1 4.2 0z"></path>
        <path class="st0" d="M-29.9 37.3l22.6 22.6c1.1 1.2 1.1 3.1-.1 4.2-1.2 1.1-2.9 1.1-4.1 0l-22.6-22.6c-1.2-1.2-1.2-3.1 0-4.2s3.1-1.2 4.2 0z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-reload" viewBox="0 0 27 32">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M25.65 18.68A12.15 12.15 0 1 1 13.5 6.67h3.77l-4.724 4.39.955.95L19.856 6 13.5 0l-.954.94 4.725 4.4H13.5A13.336 13.336 0 1 0 27 18.68h-1.35z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-round-arrow" viewBox="-14 15.1 70.9 70.9">
        <path class="st0" d="M54.9 38.6C48.3 20.2 28 10.6 9.5 17.2-8.9 23.8-18.5 44-12 62.4c.3.8 1.1 1.2 1.8.9s1.2-1.1.9-1.8c-6-16.9 2.8-35.6 19.8-41.6 16.9-6 35.6 2.8 41.6 19.8 6 16.9-2.8 35.6-19.8 41.6-9.2 3.3-19.3 2.3-27.6-2.7-.7-.4-1.6-.2-2 .5-.4.7-.2 1.5.5 1.9C20 91 41.8 85.6 51.8 68.7c5.6-9.1 6.6-20.1 3.1-30.1zM37.3 50.5c0-.8-.6-1.4-1.4-1.4H0c-.8 0-1.4.6-1.4 1.4 0 .8.6 1.4 1.4 1.4h36c.7.1 1.3-.6 1.3-1.4zm3.1 1.8L27.1 65.7c-.6.6-.6 1.5 0 2 .6.6 1.5.6 2 0l16.1-16.1c.6-.6.6-1.5 0-2.1l-16-16.1c-.6-.6-1.5-.6-2 0-.6.6-.6 1.5 0 2l15.1 15.1-1.9 1.8z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-telegram" viewBox="0 0 301.4 260.4">
        <path class="st0" d="M301.4 9.2l-47.7 240.3s-6.7 16.7-25 8.7l-110-84.3-40-19.3-67.3-22.7S1.1 128.2.1 120.2c-1-8 11.7-12.3 11.7-12.3l267.7-105c-.1 0 21.9-9.7 21.9 6.3z"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M110.3 246.9s-3.2-.3-7.2-13-24.3-79.3-24.3-79.3L240.4 51.9s9.3-5.7 9 0c0 0 1.7 1-3.3 5.7s-127 114.3-127 114.3"></path>
        <path class="st2" d="M160.9 206.2l-43.5 39.7s-3.4 2.6-7.1 1l8.3-73.7"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-telegram-style2" viewBox="0 0 26.649 26.649">
        <path d="M26.157 1.238A2.3 2.3 0 0 0 24.31.346c-.478 0-.973.133-1.472.395L1.593 11.88c-1.51.793-1.615 1.987-1.59 2.463.024.48.255 1.654 1.84 2.283L4.556 17.7a4.63 4.63 0 0 0 1.71.31c.1 0 .193-.014.29-.02-.037.05-.082.086-.116.136-.505.757-.53 1.783-.072 2.888a.887.887 0 0 0 .02.05c.804 1.78 1.697 3.788 1.805 4.067a1.828 1.828 0 0 0 1.688 1.173c1.147 0 1.487-.552 3.362-3.604.146-.225.47-.745.526-1.407l.6.242 3.01 1.226c.602.247 1.13.464 1.408.58a1.807 1.807 0 0 0 .937.263c1.368 0 1.696-1.185 1.872-1.82.087-.314.207-.75.336-1.23l4.59-16.857c.345-1.273-.08-2.086-.363-2.458zm-14.43 20.5S10.025 24.51 9.88 24.51c-.004 0-.006-.002-.008-.006-.167-.45-1.85-4.176-1.85-4.176-.31-.747-.253-1.387.28-1.387.117 0 .257.032.42.1l1.307.68c.217.148.455.277.717.38l.066.025.123.062c1.01.534 1.33.727.79 1.552zM24.79 3.225l-4.587 16.858c-.26.95-.475 1.727-.48 1.727-.003-.003-.008-.02-.008-.024 0-.006-.748-.312-1.662-.686l-3.01-1.226c-.914-.37-2.413-.97-3.332-1.323l-.15-.06-.563-.292c-.557-.427-.606-1.13-.046-1.728l9.313-9.97c.374-.4.515-.606.434-.606-.064 0-.27.133-.617.404L8.298 15.592c-.514.4-1.295.625-2.03.625-.375 0-.74-.06-1.05-.183L2.503 14.96c-.917-.362-.952-1.032-.08-1.492l21.248-11.14c.245-.13.46-.19.638-.19.457 0 .665.4.48 1.086z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-twitter" viewBox="0 0 92 74.8">
        <path class="st0" d="M92 8.8c-3.4 1.5-7 2.5-10.8 3 3.9-2.3 6.9-6 8.3-10.4-3.6 2.2-7.7 3.7-12 4.6-3.5-3.7-8.4-6-13.8-6-10.4 0-18.9 8.5-18.9 18.9 0 1.5.2 2.9.5 4.3-15.7-.8-29.6-8.3-38.9-19.7-1.6 2.8-2.6 6-2.6 9.5 0 6.5 3.3 12.3 8.4 15.7-3.1-.1-6-.9-8.5-2.4v.2c0 9.1 6.5 16.8 15.1 18.5-1.6.4-3.2.7-5 .7-1.2 0-2.4-.1-3.6-.3 2.4 7.5 9.4 13 17.6 13.1-6.5 5.1-14.6 8.1-23.4 8.1-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.3 8.4 5.4 18.3 8.5 28.9 8.5 34.7 0 53.7-28.8 53.7-53.7 0-.8 0-1.6-.1-2.4 3.9-2.7 7.1-6.1 9.6-9.9z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-facebook" viewBox="0 0 300 500" width="13px" height="26px">
        <path id="XMLID_835_" d="M81.703,165.106h33.981V305c0,2.762,2.238,5,5,5h57.616c2.762,0,5-2.238,5-5V165.765h39.064   c2.54,0,4.677-1.906,4.967-4.429l5.933-51.502c0.163-1.417-0.286-2.836-1.234-3.899c-0.949-1.064-2.307-1.673-3.732-1.673h-44.996   V71.978c0-9.732,5.24-14.667,15.576-14.667c1.473,0,29.42,0,29.42,0c2.762,0,5-2.239,5-5V5.037c0-2.762-2.238-5-5-5h-40.545   C187.467,0.023,186.832,0,185.896,0c-7.035,0-31.488,1.381-50.804,19.151c-21.402,19.692-18.427,43.27-17.716,47.358v37.752H81.703   c-2.762,0-5,2.238-5,5v50.844C76.703,162.867,78.941,165.106,81.703,165.106z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-user" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M8 0a8 8 0 1 0 8 8 8 8 0 0 0-8-8zM5.105 13.25a2.988 2.988 0 0 1 5.79 0 5.964 5.964 0 0 1-5.79 0zM8 8a1 1 0 1 1 1-1 1 1 0 0 1-1 1zm4.532 3.92a4.993 4.993 0 0 0-2.7-2.56 3 3 0 1 0-3.67 0 4.993 4.993 0 0 0-2.7 2.56 6 6 0 1 1 9.07 0z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-viber" viewBox="0 0 72.4 73.8">
        <path class="st0" d="M57.8 73.8c5.6.1 12.2-5.4 14.1-10.7 1.8-5.2-2-7.2-5.1-9.7-2.3-1.8-4.7-3.4-7-5.1-4.7-3.3-9-3.6-12.6 1.8-2 3-4.7 3.1-7.6 1.8-8-3.6-14.1-9.2-17.8-17.3-1.6-3.6-1.6-6.8 2.2-9.3 2-1.3 4-2.9 3.8-5.9-.2-3.8-9.5-16.6-13.2-18-1.5-.6-3-.5-4.6 0-8.6 2.9-12.2 10-8.8 18.3 10.2 25 28.1 42.4 52.7 53 1.5.6 3.1.9 3.9 1.1zM39.7 0c-1.3.2-4-.9-4.2 2-.1 2 2.2 1.6 3.7 1.9 18 2.8 26.3 11.3 28.6 29.5.2 1.7-.4 4.2 2 4.2 2.5.1 1.9-2.4 1.9-4.1.2-17-14.7-32.9-32-33.5zm23.1 30.5c.1-10.6-9-20.3-20.1-21.6-1.7-.2-4-1-4.4 1.4-.4 2.5 2.1 2.3 3.8 2.6 11.1 2.5 15 6.5 16.8 17.6.3 1.6-.3 4.1 2.5 3.7 1.9-.3 1.2-2.4 1.4-3.7zm-8.5-2c.1-5.1-5.7-11-10.6-10.9-1.2 0-2.3.2-2.7 1.4-.6 1.8.7 2.3 2.1 2.5 4.6.7 7 3.4 7.4 8 .1 1.2.9 2.2 2.1 2.1 1.6-.2 1.8-1.7 1.7-3.1z"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M57.8 73.8c-.8-.2-2.4-.5-3.8-1.1-24.7-10.6-42.6-28-52.7-53-3.4-8.3.1-15.4 8.7-18.3 1.5-.5 3.1-.6 4.6 0 3.7 1.3 13 14.1 13.2 18 .2 2.9-1.8 4.5-3.8 5.9-3.7 2.5-3.8 5.8-2.2 9.3 3.6 8.1 9.8 13.7 17.8 17.3 2.9 1.3 5.7 1.2 7.6-1.8 3.5-5.3 7.8-5.1 12.6-1.8 2.4 1.7 4.8 3.3 7 5.1 3.1 2.5 6.9 4.5 5.1 9.7-1.9 5.3-8.5 10.8-14.1 10.7zM39.7 0c17.3.6 32.2 16.4 32 33.5 0 1.7.6 4.2-1.9 4.1-2.4 0-1.8-2.6-2-4.2C65.5 15.3 57.2 6.7 39.1 4c-1.5-.2-3.8.1-3.7-1.9.3-3 3-1.9 4.3-2.1z"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M62.8 30.5c-.2 1.3.6 3.4-1.5 3.7-2.7.4-2.2-2.1-2.5-3.7-1.8-11-5.7-15.1-16.8-17.6-1.6-.4-4.2-.1-3.8-2.6.4-2.4 2.7-1.6 4.4-1.4 11.2 1.4 20.3 11 20.2 21.6z"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M54.3 28.5c.1 1.4-.1 2.9-1.8 3.1-1.2.1-2-.9-2.1-2.1-.5-4.6-2.9-7.2-7.4-8-1.4-.2-2.7-.7-2.1-2.5.4-1.2 1.6-1.4 2.7-1.4 5-.1 10.8 5.8 10.7 10.9z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-viber-style2" viewBox="0 0 365 394">
        <path class="st0" d="M334.5 220.9c-9.7 80.1-66.9 85.1-77.5 88.6-4.5 1.5-46.2 12.1-98.7 8.6l-56.9 63-.1-72.6-.4-.1c-76.4-21.7-73.8-103.2-73-145.9.9-42.7 8.7-77.8 32-101.3 41.8-38.8 128.1-33 128.1-33 72.8.3 107.7 22.8 115.8 30.3 27 23.5 40.7 79.8 30.7 162.4M323.8 38.4C314.2 29.4 275.6.7 189.5.3c0 0-101.5-6.3-151 40.2C10.9 68.7 1.2 110 .2 161.1c-1 51.2-2.3 147.1 88 173.1h.1v39.7s-.6 16.1 9.8 19.3c12.5 4 19.8-8.2 31.8-21.4 6.6-7.2 15.6-17.8 22.4-25.9 61.8 5.3 109.3-6.9 114.6-8.6 12.5-4.2 83-13.4 94.5-109.3 11.7-98.9-5.9-161.4-37.6-189.6"></path>
        <path class="st0" d="M268.7 232.8s-11.6-9.9-17.2-14.1c-5.3-4-13.8-9.4-18.5-12.1-8.5-4.8-17.2-1.8-20.8 3l-7.5 9.6c-3.8 4.9-9.7 4-11.2 3.7-11-2.8-22.7-9.6-34.7-21.2-12.1-11.7-19.5-23.9-22.1-36.6l-.2-.8c-.7-5.2.2-7.6 2.3-11.2l.4-.3c5-4.7 14.4-10.4 15.6-15.8 3.7-9.4-12.3-29.1-14.5-32.5 0 0-11.6-15.3-15.7-18.3-4.4-3.7-11.3-5.8-18.3-1.5l-.4.3C86 98.2 78.8 106 80.8 117.5l1 4.7c10.1 31.9 29.7 65.9 58.8 96.2 28.8 29.9 60 47.8 90.7 60.2 8 2.7 16.3.4 24.8-6.9l.1-.1c6.5-6.1 11.7-12.6 15.5-19.6v-.1c3.8-7.4 2.5-14.3-3-19.1M220.9 163c-1.2 0-2.2-1-2.3-2.2-.4-8.3-2.6-14.6-6.6-18.8-4-4.2-9.9-6.5-17.7-7-1.3-.1-2.2-1.2-2.2-2.5.1-1.3 1.1-2.3 2.4-2.2 9 .5 15.9 3.3 20.7 8.4 4.8 5.1 7.5 12.4 7.9 21.9.1 1.3-.9 2.4-2.2 2.5"></path>
        <path class="st0" d="M243.6 170.8c-1.3 0-2.3-1.1-2.3-2.4.4-15.9-4.3-29.3-13.8-39.9-4.7-5.3-10.5-9.5-17.1-12.4-6.6-3-14.4-4.8-22.9-5.4-1.3-.1-2.2-1.2-2.1-2.5.1-1.3 1.2-2.3 2.5-2.2 18.3 1.4 32.8 7.9 43.1 19.4 10.3 11.5 15.4 26.1 15 43.2-.1 1.1-1.1 2.2-2.4 2.2"></path>
        <path class="st0" d="M266.9 180.1c-1.3 0-2.3-1-2.3-2.3-.1-14-2.2-26.7-6.3-37.7-4.1-10.9-10.2-20.5-18.2-28.6-8-8-17.2-14.1-27.1-18.2-10-4.1-21.1-6.2-33.1-6.2-1.3 0-2.3-1.1-2.3-2.4 0-1.3 1-2.3 2.3-2.3 25.2.2 46.5 8.8 63.4 25.7 8.5 8.5 15 18.7 19.3 30.3 4.3 11.5 6.5 24.8 6.6 39.4 0 1.2-1 2.3-2.3 2.3z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-vk" viewBox="0 0 19.625 10.97">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M9.6 10.85h1.173a1.012 1.012 0 0 0 .534-.23.812.812 0 0 0 .16-.5s-.022-1.55.707-1.77 1.643 1.48 2.622 2.13a1.788 1.788 0 0 0 1.3.37h2.617s1.37-.1.72-1.15a8.76 8.76 0 0 0-1.946-2.19c-1.64-1.48-1.42-1.24.556-3.81 1.2-1.56 1.685-2.51 1.534-2.92a1.19 1.19 0 0 0-1.022-.32h-2.953a.757.757 0 0 0-.38.07.788.788 0 0 0-.26.33 16.18 16.18 0 0 1-1.09 2.26c-1.31 2.17-1.835 2.29-2.05 2.15-.5-.31-.374-1.26-.374-1.93 0-2.1.327-2.98-.638-3.21A5.558 5.558 0 0 0 9.435 0 6.543 6.543 0 0 0 6.99.24c-.336.16-.594.52-.437.54a1.32 1.32 0 0 1 .87.43 2.657 2.657 0 0 1 .29 1.29s.175 2.48-.4 2.78c-.4.21-.94-.22-2.11-2.18A17.492 17.492 0 0 1 4.15.95.938.938 0 0 0 3.91.63a1.256 1.256 0 0 0-.453-.17h-2.8A.962.962 0 0 0 .08.65a.57.57 0 0 0-.01.48s2.19 5.03 4.674 7.55A6.914 6.914 0 0 0 9.6 10.85z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-whatsapp" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M.057 24l1.687-6.163A11.867 11.867 0 0 1 .157 11.89C.16 5.336 5.495 0 12.05 0a11.817 11.817 0 0 1 8.413 3.488 11.824 11.824 0 0 1 3.48 8.414c-.003 6.557-5.338 11.892-11.893 11.892a11.9 11.9 0 0 1-5.688-1.448L.057 24zm6.597-3.807c1.676.995 3.276 1.59 5.392 1.592 5.448 0 9.886-4.434 9.89-9.885 0-5.462-4.416-9.89-9.882-9.892-5.452 0-9.887 4.434-9.89 9.884 0 2.225.652 3.89 1.747 5.634l-.998 3.648 3.742-.98zM18.04 14.73c-.073-.125-.27-.2-.57-.348-.296-.15-1.757-.868-2.03-.967-.272-.1-.47-.15-.67.15-.197.296-.767.966-.94 1.164-.173.197-.347.222-.644.073-.297-.15-1.255-.462-2.39-1.475-.883-.788-1.48-1.76-1.653-2.06-.173-.296-.018-.457.13-.605.134-.133.297-.347.446-.52.15-.173.2-.297.3-.496.098-.198.05-.372-.026-.52-.075-.15-.67-1.612-.916-2.207-.242-.58-.487-.5-.67-.51l-.57-.01c-.197 0-.52.074-.79.372s-1.04 1.016-1.04 2.48 1.064 2.875 1.212 3.073c.15.198 2.095 3.2 5.076 4.487.71.306 1.263.49 1.694.626.712.226 1.36.194 1.872.118.57-.085 1.758-.72 2.006-1.413.248-.695.248-1.29.173-1.414z"></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="icon-whatsapp-style2" viewBox="0 0 18.4 18.6">
        <path class="st0" d="M7.2 5.2S7.9 6.8 8 7c.1.1.1.3 0 .5-.2.2-.6.6-.6.7-.1.1-.2.2 0 .4.2.3.9 1.7 3 2.6 0 0 .2.1.4-.1s.6-.8.7-.8c.1-.1.2-.3.5-.1.3.1 1.8.8 1.8.8s.2.1.2.4c0 .3 0 1-.7 1.4-.7.4-1.2.6-1.9.5-.7-.1-2.3-.5-4-2.1 0 0-1.5-1.4-2.1-2.9-.6-1.5-.1-2.5.5-3 0 0 .4-.3.6-.3.3 0 .5-.1.6 0 .1.1.2.1.2.2z"></path>
        <path class="st0" d="M0 18.6l1.6-4.8C.7 12.4.3 10.8.3 9.1.3 4.1 4.4 0 9.4 0s9.1 4.1 9.1 9.1-4.1 9.1-9.1 9.1c-1.6 0-3.1-.4-4.4-1.1l-5 1.5zm5.1-3.2l.3.2c1.2.7 2.6 1.1 4 1.1 4.2 0 7.6-3.4 7.6-7.6s-3.4-7.6-7.6-7.6c-4.2 0-7.6 3.4-7.6 7.6 0 1.5.4 3 1.3 4.2l.2.3-.9 2.7 2.7-.9z"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg><use href="#icon-arrow"></use></svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Сейчас происходит переход от старой формы вызова к новой, как у вас в
  примере, может Apple не успел перейти к новой форме вызова и
  использует старую

`<use href="#icon-arrow"></use>`

Попробуйте старую форму вызова объекта :

`<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use>`

- Попробуйте символьный шрифт от `Google` он должен подходить ко всем
  устройствам и браузерам  Вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770153/28748) на нашем сайте на подробное
  описание, как подключать, как использовать. Если кратко, то пишите
  одну строку подключения шрифта, а вызов иконки идет по её имени.
  Напишите `Home` выведет иконку домика

*Ниже пример с нужной вам иконкой, её ещё можно стилизовать в нужный цвет:*

```css
i {
  margin: 100px 50px 50px 80px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
i:hover {
  transform: scale(10);
}

.red{color:red}
.green{color:yellowgreen}
.blue{color: dodgerblue}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons red">play_arrow</i> 
<i class="material-icons green">play_arrow</i>
<i class="material-icons blue">play_arrow</i>
```

Если анимация не нужна,- удалите соответствующие стили.

Comment: Дак старый или новый вызов зависит же от браузера? А здесь получается что Chrome на iOS не показывает иконку, а тот же Chrome но на Андроиде - без проблем. Тем более пробовали оба варианта. Безрезультатно. Получается проблема явно не в движке и/или обработке тегов. А заменить иконки да, можно. Только нюанс в том, что эти иконки уже давно распиханы по всему сайту и менять их - дело довольно трудозатратное.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin ещё вариант в этом случае - проверьте правильность подключения файла спрайта иконок к HTML или подключаете инлайн?

Comment: Хотя вот сейчас опять через browserstack проверил - через xlink:href работает. Тогда вопрос только - неужели обработка svg отдается на откуп системе? Думал браузер рендерит.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin Все мы жертвы браузерных войн и войн устройств. Не забудьте пожалуйста, поставить плюс и чекбокс :)