# Что лучше использовать - иконочный шрифт или SVG

Tags: svg, шрифты, icon, иконки

Как лучше использовать `SVG`, - собирать в спрайты, использовать `svg` файлы по отдельности, или вставлять `svg` код в `HTML`?
 И стоит ли вообще уходить с иконочного шрифта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос очень общий, поэтому ответы тоже будут общими.

Когда определитесь с направлением использования svg, задайте более конкретный вопрос, с точным описанием проблемы, с обязательным добавлением кода вашей попытки, что вы пытались сделать и не получилось.

- Сейчас наметилась тенденция отказа от использования иконочных шрифтов.

  Взамен входит в тренд [символьный шрифт от Google](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770153/28748)

*Краткая аннотация от Google:*

Шрифт обеспечивает читаемость и четкость символов, как больших, так и малых размеров. Эти иконки оптимизированы для красивого отображения на всех распространенных платформах и разрешениях дисплея.

Поддерживается всеми современными браузерами.
Поддержка IE, начинается с IE10.
[Подробное описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770153/28748), как подключать шрифты, как использовать.

- Спрайты используются активно. У нас на сайте специальный раздел -
  [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) посвященный этой теме. Пройдитесь по топикам этого
  раздела. Наверняка найдёте подходящее решение.
- Почитать о способах добавления `svg` кода в `HTML` можно [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)