# Как за "кулисами" происходит преобразование текста в картинку?

Tags: c#, .net, шрифты, графика

В общем, хотел посмотреть принцип работы метода [DrawString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing), но к моему сожалению все уперлось в вызов нативного метода:

```
[DllImport(ExternDll.Gdiplus, SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)] // 3 = Unicode
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
internal static extern int GdipDrawString(HandleRef graphics, string textString, int length, HandleRef font, ref GPRECTF layoutRect, HandleRef stringFormat, HandleRef brush);
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как за кулисами это делается?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Но ответ на него, полагаю, выходит за рамки SO. Слишком объемная тема. Тут и сглаживание, и типы шрифтов влияют, и дофига всего другого. Но я бы почитал ответ, если кто сподобится.

Answer (score 10):

Все упирается в шрифт. На всех платформах процесс рисования текста ничем особо не отличается. Каждый формат шрифтов содержит определенные данные внутри, и текст выводится посимвольно.

Если кратко рассмотреть самый популярный формат шрифтов `TrueType`, то внутри он содержит несколько таблиц с данными.

1. Глифы (`glyphs`). Здесь просто прописаны графические пути, по которым рисуется символ. Пути строятся из прямых линий и квадратичных кривых Безье (квадратичные быстрее кубических). Для экономии места один глиф может ссылаться на несколько других.
2. Соответствие между символами и глифами.
3. Таблица с метриками глифов, насколько сдвигаться относительно предыдущего символа, сдвиг по вертикали, какая длина символа и высота.
4. Кернинг (`kerning`). Необязательна таблица. Содержит информацию о том, насколько менять расстояние между специфическими парами символов. Например, если посмотреть на комбинацию следующих 2 латинских символов - AW - то видно, что W "наезжает" на A. Если шрифт моноширинный, то эта таблица отсутствует, так как символы всегда имеют одинаковую ширину, и не сдвигаются никогда.
5. Лигатуры (`ligatures`). Необязательная таблица. Содержит соответствия между комбинациями символов в исходной строке и специальными глифами. На примере ниже показано, как выглядят лигатуры в шрифте `Calibri`, и как символы выглядят по отдельности (что бы "сломать" лигатуру использовался символ U+FEFF посредине):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица с глифами может дополнительно содержать инструкции (`hints`) для виртуальной машины TrueType. Эти инструкции могут сдвигать некоторые точки символа, что бы он лучше выглядел на пиксельной сетке. На примере ниже символ `m`. Слева - точки просчитаны простой аппроксимацией, справа - после применения хинтов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На платформах Microsoft применяется технология ClearType для сглаживания. На свое усмотрение эта технология может игнорировать некоторые хинты, и рисовать символы по-своему.

Источник:
https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=iws-chapter08

Comment: Еще вот такой мануал нашел официальный https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6.html

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну это мануал уже для разработчиков шрифтов, или для тех, кто захочет сам прочитать ttf файл и нарисовать текст :)

Comment: Ещё стоило бы про лигатуры вспомнить.

Comment: @Qwertiy а что с ними особенного? Это вроде как просто отдельные символы в юникоде

Comment: @Qwertiy у лигатур отдельные глифы и коды. Т.е. это самостоятельный символ с точки зрения шрифта.

Comment: @rdorn, с точки зрения шрифта - да, а вот с точки зрения текстового файла - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy а пример можно, ни разу такого не попадалось еще

Comment: @rdorn, [можно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/770084/178988). И ещё [вот такое](https://habr.com/post/243005/) сейчас в моде - даже на [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla) можно увидеть, если обычную лямбду (`var f = x => 0`) написать: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0tWq.png

Comment: @Zergatul, кажется, ты путаешь лигатуры с эмоджи.

Comment: @Qwertiy круто, не знал что такое уже появилось =) В любом случае оно пока в экспериментальном состоянии. так что бум ждать хотя бы полных спецификаций, а лучше стандарт. Пока стандарта или хотя бы публичной спеки нет - реализуй как хочешь.

Comment: @rdorn, почему в экспериментальном? Оно давным давно используется для сочетаний букв типа fft.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за замечание, добавил и про лигатуры